Windows keeps changing the default format of my audio devices
I have an audio interface (M-Audio M-Track Duo), and windows keeps changing the "Speakers" and "Line 1/2" default format to 32bit.
Is there a way to keep windows from changing the settings? Regedit? 3rd party tools?
It has happened on Windows 10, Windows 11, through months of updates and different versions of the device drivers. It happens after rebooting the PC, and sometimes even during usage. I've resorted to using scripts, but I would REAAALLY prefer just having the problem fixed, as it does result in artifacts.

If the script is for the Registry, consider changing ownership of the key and preventing SYSTEM from changing it -- make it read-only. Caveat: make a disk image or system backup first.

the script just uses nirsoft's command line tool and just manually changes the format, but it's not really reliable. i have no clue how i would change the format from the registry
